# DataLayer is adding event but not getting fired in google analytics events

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have implemented GTM in my website. The events are adding in dataLayer but are not firing in google analytics report
HTML:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript>
    <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MBZH97"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<script>
    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
            'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-MBZH97');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Push Code:

```
dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'GAevent', 'eventCategory': 'Login', 'eventAction': 'Complete', 'eventLabel': 'Cookie' });
```

Console Result Image:[image]

GTM Tag Image[image]

Comment: To exclude the obvious, do you have configured a trigger ? The event will not fire on it'S own, you need a trigger based on your "GAEvent" custom event (do not be confused by the fact that GTM events and GA events are named similarly, "event" here refers to two unrelated things).

Comment: I did not get you. Trigger mean where in GTM interface or in code?

Comment: Pushing data to the dataLayer will make it available for use in  GTM, but will not do anything by itself. You need to create "variables" in the interface that pick the values from the dataLayer, a Google Analytics tag that sends the data and a trigger that fires the GA tag when the "event" key in the dataLayer receives the value "GAEvent".  You find those three things on the left-hand menu when you enter the admin section for your container.

Comment: I have added the trigger named as 'GAEvent' and add tag against this but still this is not getting fired. 
If i add tag on 'All pages', those events get fired but not this one.

I have attached image of GTM too

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped - this is case sensitive and your variable is "GAevent" (small "e"), not "GAEvent" with a capital "E".

Comment: still no luck. Is it like some cache issue, may be it is not getting new changes?

Comment: Are you checking in realtime ? Standard report will take a couple of hours to update.

Comment: yes got it, my bad I am not publishing new changes :) 
Thanks alot for your time